# clear() method of ByteBuffer in java

Tags: java

I was reading about DatagramChannel in one of the tutorial website.They explained the following sample program

```
String newData = "New String to write to file..."
                    + System.currentTimeMillis();

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
buf.clear();
buf.put(newData.getBytes());
buf.flip();

int bytesSent = channel.send(buf, new InetSocketAddress("example.com", 80));
```

They have added the line buf.clear() after created ByteBuffer class object. clear() is for clear the buffer.But initially we dont need to clear right??.if it is needed there,then why should we use ??.
thanks.(sorry, if any grammer mistake)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's just a bad tutorial/website. It's not needed in a situation where you've just allocated a brand new `ByteBuffer`. You could just use

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(newData.getBytes());
```

to get rid of the `put()` and `flip()` too.

Comment: flip() is used to change mode (from/to) write (to/from) read mode.what is default mode?? if it is write mode,  buf.flip() is wrong before channel.send(buf, new InetSocketAddress("example.com", 80)); line or it is meaningless only write right??

Comment: There's no "read mode" or "write mode". Flip just flips the buffer, setting position to 0 and limit to old position, like the javadoc explains.